# Box2d body dimensions go higher in ipad non retina

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-x, box2d

I'm developing a game in cocos2dX. I'm using box2d for physics simulation. I'm creating a rectangular body having width of 768 and run it in ipad and ipad retina. In ipad retina the body width and device width are the same. But in ipad(non-retina) the body width is double the device width. But if I display a sprite it happens in the opposite direction(for sprites I understood why it happens). But for box2d bodies why this is happening in opposite? how to fix this?

Here is my code.

I've set PTM_RATIO to 64.

```
    b2BodyDef blockBodyDef;
    blockBodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
    blockBodyDef.position.Set(H_screenSize.width/2/PTM_RATIO,H_screenSize.height/2/PTM_RATIO);

    //blockBodyDef.userData = block_sprite;
    H_block_body = H_world->CreateBody(&blockBodyDef);

    b2PolygonShape blockshape;
    blockshape.SetAsBox(768/PTM_RATIO,B_HEIGHT/PTM_RATIO);
    b2FixtureDef blockShapeDef;
    blockShapeDef.shape = &blockshape;
    blockShapeDef.density = 100.0f;
    blockShapeDef.friction = 10.0f;
    blockShapeDef.restitution = 0.0f;
    H_block_body->CreateFixture(&blockShapeDef);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code. A typical and common problem is to apply PTM (pixel to meter) ratio incorrectly. You multiply box2d positions by PTM to scale up to points, and you divide by PTM if you apply a position or size from nodes to box2d. However you should not take CCContentScaleFactor into account in these calculations.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I've posted the code. I have a doubt about setting the body dimensions. blockshape.SetAsBox(768/PTM_RATIO,B_HEIGHT/PTM_RATIO); If change the PTM_RATIO the dimensions passed to the blockshape will also change. But in the screen the dimensions are not changing.

Comment: It was because I misunderstood the function blockshape.SetAsBox(768/PTM_RATIO,B_HEIGHT/PTM_RATIO); It is taking half the width and height of the rectangle body. I thought I am passing the exact width and height.